# Hadoop 1.2.1 - I need to remove a file from HDFS

Tags: hadoop

Good Day,

I have added a file to HDFS via the command

```
hadoop fs -put query1.txt .
```

Now I would like to remove it but I don't have the HDFS location of the file. Is there any way to remove it

Comment: By default it would go into the home directory of the user issuing the command.eg. hdfs would send it to /user/hdfs

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the file using this command.

`hadoop fs -rmr query1.txt`

By default it will store in /user/(hadoopuser) in your hdfs path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to see the HDFS file location

```
hadoop fs -ls 
hadoop fs -ls /
```

You will see the hdfs location of your file.

To remove the file use below command

```
hadoop fs -rmr query1.txt
```